# dotMemoryUnit run tests under x64 process

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I now have successfully run tests using Resharper in 64-bit mode. I created a test checking memory usage using

```
dotMemory.Check(memory => ...);
```

To run this test using the profiler, dotMemory extended the contextmenu of a test:

[image: dotMemory Unit context menu]

However, when using this option the dotMemory test runner wrapper seems to ignore the Resharper settings/ test.runsettings file.

How can I run MSTest tests using the dotMemory Unit wrapper in 64-bit mode from the Resharper plugin in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why do you think it is running in x86 mode? I checked on my Win7 x64 and test runs inside x64 process.
What R# settings do you mean, R#=>Options=>Unit Testing=>Default platform architecture OR Unit test Session window=>Options=>Platform?

Comment: All our tests explicitly check for x64 bit mode, and fail asap when not in x64 bit.

Comment: 1. How do you check it? 2.What R# settings do you mean, R#=>Options=>Unit Testing=>Default platform architecture OR Unit test Session window=>Options=>Platform?

Comment: 1. We check 64 bitness by always executing `Assert.IsTrue(Environment.Is64BitProcess, "not 64bit");`. 2. R#=>Options=>Unit Testing=>Default platform architecture. I was not aware of the bitness optoin in the UnitTestSessions window. I will try this later today.

Comment: R#=>Options=>Unit Testing=>Default platform architecture controls with what value of "Options=>Platform" will be create a NEW unit test session. If session is already exists only "Options=>Platform" takes into account. Please try to set it manually and write if it helps or not, I still cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have tested it and I got it to work now by changing the Options -> Platform option in the UnitTestSessions window. If you post an answer, I will mark it is such. If not, I will add an answer were I explain the steps I took to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Options->Platform" chooser on the toolbar of Unit test session window to set an architecture.

R#->Options->Unit Testing->Default platform architecture only controls with what value of "Options->Platform" a **new** unit test session will be created.